# Building a DLL independent of the MSVC runtime using Visual C++

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I write a simple DLL, in C, with no explicit dependency to external function: no `#include`, `malloc` or `memcpy`. It builds under modern Visual Studio (express 2022), but with a dependency to VCRUNTIME140.dll, part of the "universal" [MSVC runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist) for VS 2015, 2017, 2019, 2022. Thus my DLL is unusable unless that runtime is installed. I'd want to fix that, while keeping my code a DLL (no static library).

I found two options that work:

- Build my DLL using `/MT` (Multithreaded runtime) rather than `/MD` (Multithreaded DLL runtime), with the effect that the runtime is included in the library. However the size of my DLL balloons by over 100kB, and I'm uncomfortable about redistributing that object code that I know I don't need.
- Build my DLL with the [Tiny C Compiler](https://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html). Experimentally, it's pin-compatible with applications which reference my DLL using the .lib file produced by Visual C++. However I'm worried that could introduce a hidden problem (like an unsaved register).

Is there a clean solution under Visual Studio?

If that matters: my `DLL` has no `DllMain`, `DllRegisterServer`, `DllUnregisterServer`. It exposes a single function, no global, but has static constants.

---

I tried to link with `/NODEFAULTLIB` but got hit by
`LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup`

Comment: Check the VC documentation for `static linking` - I can't remember the details.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I want to produce a DLL, not a statically linked library. I also do not want to weak-link.

Comment: `/MT` causes the linker to see a static library containing the runtime.  The linker will then discard unneeded objects and only the portions of the static library you depend on will be included in your DLL.  Your question isn't very clear what your thought was bad about `/MT`.

Comment: What you do need to be concerned about, and is inherent of your wish to avoid a prerequisite installation of the MSVC runtime, is that your DLL will have its own allocator incompatible with the one your caller is using.  So you can not deallocate memory which came from outside your DLL, nor can you return newly allocated memory and expect the caller to deallocate it.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the feedback. I now explain my issue with `/MT`; basically bloat. My library needs no allocation beyond a little stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking with `/NODEFAULTLIB` and `/NOENTRY` seems to do the job. Now both `/MD` and `/MT` generate a library with no MSVC runtime dependency as did `/MD`, and like 4kB instead of >100kB as did `/MD`.

Comment: There's a very good chance that initialization of your global variables, including constants, will not happen if you remove the entry-point.

Comment: Just understand that if you do this you can't rely on the C Runtime library. Any function, you would need to replicate yourself.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: At least, my `static const uint8_t foo[4]={2,3,5,7};` are usable, and that's enough for my purposes.